# Finding a formula for the expected value

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume we have $n$ dice, and each die has $10$ sides. We roll the dice and add all subsets of dice that are of equal value, then find the highest number. For example if we roll five dice and get: $1,1,5,5,7$ we have $2\times 1=2,\  2\times 5=10 ,\ 1\times 7=7$, so our result is then $10$ since that is the highest number.
How to find a formula for finding the expected value for $n$ dice?

Comment: This looks pretty hard. For small $n$ you could solve it on a computer. For large $n$, the probability that the $10$s win goes to $1$, so the expected value goes to $10n/10=n$.

Comment: If you are looking for a formula to compute, you have $\mathbb{E}( \max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant 10} k \sum 1_{X_i=k})$